# Why there is exit code 1 - executing R script from PHP

Tags: php, r

I am trying to execute the following simple R script via PHP but I am always getting exit code 1 if I put `library()` function call.

```
library('optparse')
quit()
```

The PHP script 'test.php' is given as:

```
<?php
$calc = exec("Rscript test.r", $R_output, $R_exitcode);
print $calc_routine;
```

The script produces exit code 0 when I remove `library()` function call, so it's sure that R script is located correctly.

Comment: What is the content of $R_output? Is the package optparse installed in R (wherever you run your php script on)?

Comment: @Linus $R_output is an empty array and yes I can load the library 'optparse' in an interactive session.

Comment: What's the exit code when you call R from elsewhere? In what environment (CLI or webserver) does the PHP code run?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am not sure if I understood the question completely but if I run the same script using Rscript, then the exit code is 0 (checked using ''$ echo $?''). The PHP code is running under XAMPP webserver.

Comment: So, what if you call PHP from the commandline and calls R from PHP in turn?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Interesting. At command line, if I call PHP (without webserver), the $R_exitcode is 0. So, is it webserver side issue?

Comment: If other programs called from the webserver behave the same, you can pretty much rule out any influence of R. Notable differences when running in a webserver are the user (including e.g. permissions to read/write files) and also whether starting any processes at all is allowed.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You mean permissions related to reading/writing library files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an environment variable](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) called `R_LIBS_USER` that tells R where to look for libraries. By default, it is set to a subdirectory in your home directory. Of course when called from a web server, you will be not be running it – the home directory will be different.

First you'll need to determine what your library directory is. From R, [call `.libPaths()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/libPaths) to get it.

Then, you can either tell PHP about the updated value:

```
<?php
setenv("R_LIBS_USER", "/path/to/your/libraries");
$calc = exec("Rscript test.r", $R_output, $R_exitcode);
```

Or, in your R code, use .libPaths with a parameter to set the library path to the new value:

```
.libPaths('/path/to/your/libraries')
library('optparse')
quit()
```

Comment: good call. when php exec calls are mysteriously failing, environment variables being set to something unexpected is always a good place to start looking